# How do I install a new locale in the Flex SDK?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, localization

I have a flex application being developed in Spanish, and I'd like to build it using a Spanish locale. However, the only locales installed in my SDK are en_US and ja_JP. Is there a site or resource where I can get other sets of locale files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that version 4 of the SDK has 16 different locales represented (including Spanish), so that may be useful for you.  Although I have to say this has never been an issue for me since the only thing that I've really needed to localize were strings in the UI that I've created rather than strings from the SDK.  I honestly can't think of any strings from the SDK that get exposed in the UI.

Comment: Specifically, I'm getting complaints about the "Initializing..." message on the loading screen.

Comment: Oh, good point, didn't think of that.  I've noticed that Flex 4 no longer has text when loading, it just shows the progress bar.  Might be another reason to migrate to 4 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the copylocale in the bin folder of the SDK
This does leave you having to translate though.

For example, cd to your Flex SDK directory and execute in cmd:

```
bin\copylocale en_US jp_JP
```